# OP Forgot to add tag for a post (which is one week old), how to add it and bring back the post active?

Tags: support, tags, edits

[How to use Bootstrap JavaScript Components with ngx-bootstrap in Angular 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541961/how-to-use-bootstrap-javascript-components-with-ngx-bootstrap-in-angular-7)

OP who has raised the above post seems to have forgotten to add an important tag due to which he might have lost good visibility. Today, while I was looking for an answer to a particular coding issue I came across the same post and added the "angular" tag for better visibility.

However, I'm not sure how I can make it listed at the top of the posts which are tagged under "angular".

I've checked that, and it was not appearing. Can someone help?

Comment: I see... Let me check it.

Comment: This should probably be asked on Meta Stack Overflow instead. :)

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry about that as well. :p

Comment: Not sure what you ask. Every edit bumps the question to the top of the "last active" list, which is the default sort. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard It's not actually the default sort.

Comment: @Servy care to explain please?

Comment: @ShadowTheCurlyBracedWizard What is there to explain?  "Active" is not the default sorting for the question list.  What else do you want explained?

Comment: @Servy OK thanks, just checked. While the default homepage sort of "interesting" relies heavily on last activity, tag pages indeed have default sort of "Newest". Since I chose "Active" years ago I've never changed it, hence my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of the writing of this answer, that post is 12th in the list of "active" posts in angular, given that 11 other posts have had activity since your edit.  If you're sorting by some other metric, such as newest, then it's probably not going to be near the top.

Comment: My bad.. I should've checked that..

Comment: Thanks Servy!.. Thanks for this heads-up.